# INVOKE_DEFAULT cancels selection while EXEC_DEFAULT doesn't

Tags: python, scripting, select

I'm writing a script for exporting convex shapes in a proprietary format. I have an option for V-HACD auto-generating and also an option for manual tweaking of V-HACD settings before exporting. The first option works fine (using EXEC_DEFAULT) but the second one doesn't (using INVOKE_DEFAULT). In the second scenario, V-HACD warns me that no mesh is selected even though they should be selected.
Here's the relevant part of the script:

```
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action="SELECT") # All meshes should be selected
    if manual:
        bpy.ops.object.vhacd("INVOKE_DEFAULT") # This doesn't work
    else:
        bpy.ops.object.vhacd("EXEC_DEFAULT") # This does
```

The addon in question: https://github.com/andyp123/blender_vhacd

Comment: I assume you're using this [third-party add-on](https://github.com/kmammou/v-hacd)?

Comment: I'm using a 2.8 port but yes. I'll add that into the question.